# How to solve lint error - unexpected await inside a loop when calling aws connect api which returns a next token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I am making calls to aws connect which returns a number of queues and a next-token to fetch the next set. Once all the queues are returned in 'n' calls, nextToken is retuned as null which I used to terminate the do-while loop.

```
let token;
do{
  let {queues,nextToken}= await connect.listQueues(params); //pseudo code
  params['NextToken']=nextToken;
  token=nextToken;
  //do some processing
}while(nextToken);
```

All of this is working fine but lint warns that: `unexpected await inside a loop.` Is there a better way to do this so that I avoid the lint error and also achieve what I am trying to do here ?

Comment: what linter is complaining? this makes reasonable sense

Comment: unexpected await inside a loop

Comment: no which _tool_...

Comment: eslint...........

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

ended up disabling the eslint rule.

```
/*eslint-disable no-await-in-for-loop eslint-disable *\
```